# Duplicated queue jobs when running service in cluster

Tags: node.js, docker, queue, cluster-computing, bull

I'm new to working with distributed queue systems, so I guess my question may be weird. But really hope to find a solution.

I have a Node.js microservice that uses *[Bull Queue](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull)*. The service works with 2 queues: it subscribes on the `firstQueue` and produces jobs for the `secondQueue` when getting the message.

The return value of the `firstQueue` contains data for multiple jobs for the `secondQueue`. So I produce the jobs like this:

```
firstQueue.on('global:completed', async (jobId, returnValue) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(returnValue);
    
    for (const task of data) {
        secondQueue.add(task, jobSettings);  
    }     
});
```

And I have the process worker for the `secondQueue` in the same service:

```
const workerProcess = require('./workerProcess');
firstQueue.process(workerProcess);
```

It works well, but I want to process these `secondQueue` tasks in parallel. The microservice is running as Docker Service in Docker Swarm mode. So the first decision I made was to use `replicas: N` option for Docker service. But here is a problem: I want to have replicated process worker for `secondQueue`, but I'm also getting replicated `firstQueue` listener, hence I read the same message from `firstQueue` N times. Actually, I want to receive the message only once and just parallelize job processes.

I think, using of `replicas` option for Docker service cannot help me. And I have no idea how to achieve what I want. Are there some ways/patterns to do that? Or maybe I've chosen the wrong architecture for my microservice?